# Is it safe to assume memory page size is a power of two?

Tags: c, linux

I am currently working on a portable C program which makes use of the memory page size (as returned by `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`). I know most often page size is a power of two to allow efficient management using bitwise operations; I found no guarantee of this anywhere, though. So how safe is it to assume page size is a power of two? Are there any examples of architectures not satisfying this condition?

Comment: As the MMU does not include a divider, but uses masking of bits to split the virtual address to the parts for table-walk, it is a safe bet.

Comment: Why would you need to assume if you can retrieve the size?

Comment: @skrrgwasme: His algorithm might take benefit from arrays of powers of two. For example a FFT will.

Comment: @skrrgwasme: Same reason it usually is a power of two: being able to use bitwise operations, also being able to repeatedly half the pages.

Comment: Until they come out with ternary logic based computers, you are pretty safe. :)

Comment: @olaf Checking your assumptions won't stop you from using optimizations. It just gives you the chance to present an error message or fall back on a naive unoptimized implementation if that assumption was false. You lose nothing by making a simple check before relying on an assumption.

Comment: @victorschubert See my reply to Olaf.

Comment: @skrrgwasme: That's not an assumption, but a technically well-founded statement. So you really think a PMMU will use a divider to support pagesizes other than powers of two? That's somewhat ridiculous, as it would take more clocks for the division than the complete table-walk! While  one could add a check for such nonsense, it would be completely nonsense to add fallback solutions for a case which has zero chance to occur. Worse: algorithms like the FFT **require** an array size of powers of two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I can't find any explicit statement that the page size is required to be a power of two, I think it's a very reasonable assumption. The POSIX concept of "alignment" (see `posix_memalign`) is defined in terms of powers of two, not arbitrary divisors - specifically, the alignment argument must be a power-of-two multiple of `sizeof(void*)` - and it seems that you should be able to achieve page-aligned memory with this interface. Beyond that, all real-world architectures use power-of-two page sizes, and have no reasonable justification for ever changing that; anything else is significantly more costly in hardware.

Comment: I did not know about the `memalign` family of functions; now I know I'll need them, too. Thanks!

Comment: Any other page-size would require a true division/remainder in the highly time-critical path of the PMMU and the caches. Namely architectures x86, ARM, PPC, POWER, MIPS, SPARC, SuperH, ColdFire/68XXX, have all powers of 2 page-sizes. Show me one without and I show you a very broken design ...

Comment: @VictorSchubert: Always use the most common functions. The C standard already provides `aligned_alloc`, no need to use the posix-version (as you already asked about a portability issue). Also: they need not be supported by an implementation. From the man-page: "The posix_memalign() function is part of the Advisory Information option and need not be provided on all implementations."

Comment: @Olaf: POSIX has been around a lot longer, and is more widely implemented, than C11, but the point of mentioning `posix_memalign` here has nothing to do with whether you should do it, but rather shedding some light on POSIX's ideas of alignment that are (or should be) related to concepts of page size.

Comment: @R..: There is a C11 compliant implementation available for every relevant POSIX-compliant system. And one for most non-POSIX hosted environments. So the set of systems supported by C11 should be larger than the set of POSIX systems. A system not providing C11 compatibility will likely also not follow POSIX.

Comment: @Olaf: Again that's outside the scope of why I brought up `posix_memalign`. The scope of this whole question is POSIX since it involves `mmap` and `_SC_PAGE_SIZE`, and the point was not to suggest an interface to use, but to shed light on the attitudes of the standard on alignment concepts.

Answer (score 1):

1) It's guaranteed via the computation of the page size in the Linux kernel. This isn't a guarantee in the sense of a formal standard, but it's unlikely that this approach would change for all the reasons already stated.

From `/usr/src/kernels/<your_kernel>/include/asm-generic/page.h`:

```
#define PAGE_SHIFT      12
#ifdef __ASSEMBLY__
#define PAGE_SIZE       (1 << PAGE_SHIFT)
#else
#define PAGE_SIZE       (1UL << PAGE_SHIFT)
#endif
```

As you can see, the page size is actually defined in terms of shifts, and thus will always be powers of two. Note that this code is used for the generic architecture case, and that specific architectures define different values for `PAGE_SHIFT`.

2) As a practical matter, you can get the page size via the `getconf` program by typing `getconf PAGESIZE` at a terminal. This could be used to generate a quick compile-time check that would be far easier than coding up a likely never-used backup case.

3) The page size is determined by the MMU. Thus, the closest you'll get to a formal standard is the processor documentation from the various manufacturers. For example, table 4-1 from volume 3A of the Intel Software Developer's Manual gives an exhaustive list of paging modes and page sizes in Intel processors:

[image: Intel Page Sizes]

4) I can tell you that every major processor architecture uses page sizes that are powers of two.

5) There's actually a major problem - fragmentation of the physical memory space - if you don't. The page and the page frame size need to be equal, so if you have a non power of two page size then you've got non power of two page frames. Suppose you're on a system with a page frame size of 3000 and (for simplicity of example) 32 total page frames. Thus, physical addresses are 17 bits long- 5 bits to select the page frame and 12 bits to address 3000 bytes.

```
00000 0000 0000 0000
\___/ \____________/
  |             \
(page frame)  (page offset)
```

If the page size (page frame size) is equal to a power of two, then the entire physical memory space from `00000 0000 0000 0000` to `11111 1111 1111 1111` are valid addresses. If the page frame size was 3000, then you'd have a gap in the physical address space from `XXXXX 1011 1011 0111` (last valid address) through `XXXXX 1111 1111 1111`. This isn't to say that such a system couldn't be used, but it'd add horrendous complexity for no reason I can think of.

Comment: x86 only covers a minority of all Linux implementations, less if you consider other OS, too. While I agree there is no reason to assume someone would implement other than powers-of-2 page-sizes a single CPU documentation hardly is proof. You last paragraph is a bit confused. A gap in the physical address would also be one in the logical space, which is intolerable. But dividing (with remainder) would avoid both. It is just the ration of costs (time and space) vs. benefit of such a unit would be unacceptable.

Comment: The MMU can always do some magic to provide a logically consistent virtual address space on top of a fragmented physical memory space, so the virtual memory space is not necessarily fragmented. The physical memory can't get around it though.

Comment: As I wrote, that would involve true divison including remainder instead of masking! And that is definitively a no-go, as every other CPU- and hardware-designer can confirm!